# Displaying XML Content Associated with Drop Down Menu with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to make a drop down menu to display XML attribute values, and have the drop down affect a list of other XML values.

Here is a sample of the XML:

```
<XML_DATA item=“VariousPeoples”>
    <Peoples>
        <Person nationality="american" name="Buzz Aldrin">Aldrin, E. Buzz</Person>
        <Person nationality="american" name="Neil Armstrong">Armstrong, Neil</Person>
        <Person nationality="canadian" name="Chris Hadfield">Hadfield, Chris</Person>
        <Person nationality="russian" name="Yuri Gagarin">Gagarin, Yuri</Person>
        <Person nationality="russian" name="Valentina Tereshkova">Tereshkova, Valentina</Person>
    </Peoples>
</XML_DATA>
```

Here is the JQuery/Ajax. I am able to populate the drop down of nationalities and list of names.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "feed.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    complete: function(data,status) { parseXml(data.responseText); }
  });
    function parseXml(xml)
    {
        // Populate the menu
        var arr = new Array();
        $(xml).find("Person").each(function ()
        {
        var option = $(this).attr("nationality");
        if($.inArray(option, arr) > -1) {
               // Do nothing 
             } else {
           $("#mySelect").append("<option>" + option + "</option>");
           arr.push(option);
             }
         });

        // Populate the list
        var arr2 = new Array();
        $(xml).find("Person").each(function ()
        {
        var option2 = $(this).attr("name");
        if($.inArray(option2, arr2) > -1) {
               // Do nothing 
            } else {
           $("#myList").append("<li>" + option2 + "</li>");
           arr2.push(option2);
            }
         });

        }
});
```

And the HTML:

```
<select id="mySelect">
    <option>--Country--</option>
</select>

<ul id="myList">
</ul>
```

This works quite well for displaying the two independently, but I would like the the drop down selection to alter the list of names. So if "American" was selected, only "Buzz Aldrin", and "Neil Armstrong" would appear below.

Comment: `I would like` is not a question.... so...what is your question?

Comment: @charlietfl my apologies, my English is not very good. To rephrase my question, I am attempting to have a dropdown menu populated with XML attributes affect a list of related XML attributes. I have tried to achieve this, and so far above is the successful components of my code. How would I build upon this? Again, I am terribly sorry about my English. It is not my native language.